# Bash script while [ pgrep ] not working as expected

Tags: bash

I am trying to use the shell command (`while`) to determine if a command is running, if not already running start the command, if already running wait and recheck and once it ends start the command again. Note I am trying to ensure only one instance of a specific command is running at any one time.  Here is what I have so far.

```
CSKIP=$(pgrep -x comskip)
while [ $CSKIP ]; do
    echo "comskip is already running"
    sleep 30s;
done
$COMSKIP --ini=$INI $1 # run comskip >> $LOG
```

My results:

If `COMSKIP` is not already running it starts which is what I want. However, if `COMSKIP` is already running I get an endless loop of "comskip is already running"

Comment: Indent code 4 spaces by typing Ctl-k or using the `{}` tool in the SO editor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `pgrep` every time through the loop. You're just setting the variable once, and never updating it, so every test gets the same result.

Instead of testing the output, you can just test the exit status; it's `0` when it finds a match, non-zero when there's no match or it gets an error.

```
while pgrep -x comskip >/dev/null; do
    echo "comskip is already running"
    sleep 30s;
done
$COMSKIP --ini=$INI $1 # run comskip >> $LOG
```

Comment: Thanks so much that worked. I've been banging my head trying to fix this for days. So that I understand >dev/null empties the result of pgrep -x comskip as it passes it on to either do thereby forcing it to process the pgrep again? Without the >/dev/null the prior result is utilized hence my previous endless loop problem.

Comment: It's just so you don't see the output of `pgrep`.

Comment: All you care about is whether it succeeds or fails, you don't want the process info printed every time through the loop.

Comment: It's just normal output redirection, like `echo foo > filename`